# Mysql Vb.net Parameterized Query Not Passing value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am converting a vb.net application which previously ran on SQL Server 2008 Back end to MySQL.I got stuck at some part where i use Parameterized Queries.
Below is the code i am using.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select   A.Product_Code,A.Product_Name from Product_Master A inner join Barcode B on A.Product_Code=B.Product_code where B.Batch_no=@bno and A.Product_del=0 and B.product_type=@type Limit 1"
AssignConnection(cmd)
If ConnectToDB() Then
      With cmd
         .Parameters.Add("@bno", txtBatchno.Text)
         .Parameters.Add("@type", IIf(Me.Tag = 0, "SFG", "W"))
      End With
```

also i have checked adding parameter like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bno", txtBatchno.Text)` and  `cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@type", IIf(Me.Tag = 0, "SFG", "W")))`,but found none of those working.

the same query holds value in parameters,i have verified using immediate windows.Also i have tried running the resultant query in Workbench and I get values there.

Any help Appreciated as i Have little Time left.

**Updates:**

to know what query string is Passing to db,i have tried using below code,

```
Dim query As String = cmd.CommandText
        For Each p As MySqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
            query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString())
        Next
```

and found that the values are passing `without single qoutes(')` and query gives error in workbench also.

Comment: Can't remember the last time I did this, but isn't meant to be something like .Parameters.Add("@name", DataType).Value = MyValue

Comment: i tried with the same too..but same result..

Comment: Expressions like "gives an error" or "it doesn't work" or similar are not helpful (for you to get a quick answer and for the answer to be reliable at all). After a quick look, your code is wrong for various reasons: firstly, `Me.Tag` is an object and consequently `Me.Tag = 0` is likely to provoke problems (i.e., it might work under your specific conditions, although it might also fail. Perhaps you should write `Option Strict On` what would avoid this kind of not-too-right situations to occur at all). But what is more important: `cmd.Parameters.Add(` has various overloads and none of them...

Comment: ... accepts what you are doing. Why not plainly maximising how helpful VS is? It tells you expressly the arguments that each function is expecting. Why not plainly following its advices? Can you please analyse your code/situation properly, remove all the evident errors and ask an on-topic question (i.e., problem which might be relevant to someone else with a basic understanding of the given situation)?

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact query text used? In your example above you don't use parameters and adding them to your command parameters collection is useless because the query doesn't contains any parameter placeholder. In this context your UPDATE doesn't make sense, apart from being conceptually wrong what are you replacing here? And after replacing how do you manage to update the CommandText of the command?

Comment: sorry the query i had given was a work aroung to check actual working of query.in a hurry i have posted wrong code.I have updated the question with actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, going to break this down so I can later reference how to parameterize SQL queries to prevent SQL injection attacks.  When you parameterize a query, you remove the need to do string concatenation, which your example still show's you doing:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select   A.Product_Code,A.Product_Name from Product_Master A inner join Barcode B on A.Product_Code=B.Product_code where B.Batch_no='" & txtBatchno.Text & "' and A.Product_del=0 and B.product_type='" & IIf(Me.Tag = 0, "SFG", "W") & "' Limit 1"
```

To properly parameterize, it would be something like this (varies based on the SQL server instance rules for parameters, which varies by vendor):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select   A.Product_Code,A.Product_Name from Product_Master A inner join Barcode B on A.Product_Code=B.Product_code where B.Batch_no=@bNo and A.Product_del=0 and B.product_type=@type Limit 1"
```

Now that we've got a properly parameterized query, I'll address your updates:

1. Parameter values never contain single quotes.  That is all taken care of for you, based on the datatype of the column you're parameterizing.
2. The query as written WILL FAIL in just about any query tool if it doesn't recognize your parameterization.  The trick here is to know that if you don't get prompted for values for the parameter variables you've included in your query you will have to change the structure of your parameters (typically @ precedes variables in T-SQL (MSSQL), been long enough that I don't recall if you can use the same syntax in parameterized queries. In Oracle, you can either use ? and supply the values in order of appearance, or to use named, preceed with :)

Comment: thanks for the answer.but it was my mistake the query i posted in my question is actually a workaround to check if its other error than parameters accepting values.i have updated my question with actual code i used,which is same given in your query(the same gives me error `input string was not in correct format`)

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.Parameters.Add()` is an old overload that is now obsolete. It isn't doing what you think.

You need to either use `.AddWithValue()` or even better, use one of the `.Add()` overloads that allows you specify the parameter type... and there are some [reasons why you should choose the latter](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: but with the same `.AddWithValue()` i am getting error when passing single qoutes(') or some special characters.it isnt doing the usual escaping when using parameterization.

Comment: Query parameters **never** escape data! They _quarantine_ it. This is an important distinction to understand. It means the code you used to look at the actual sql query does not do what you think it does. What error do you get when you use AddWithValue()?

Comment: Articles such as [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [How to pollute your Plan Cache with parameterized SQL statements](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/07/20/how-to-pollute-your-plan-cache-with-parameterized-sql-statements/): "AddWithValue is very, very EVIL: it just derives the actual data type based on the parameter value that you supplied. NEVER EVER USE it!" suggest that it may not be a good idea to even include the method name as a possible suggestion.